# in pybind11, is it possible to determine whether a py::object is a py::dict?

Tags: c++, pybind11

If, in c++, I have an object in hand of type `py::object`, how can I most easily determine whether that object is a `py::dict`? `dynamic_cast` doesn't seem to work - I guess `py::object` isn't actually polymorphic.

Comment: Using [`isinstance`](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#_CPPv4I0_N6detail11enable_if_tINSt10is_base_ofI6object1TE5valueEiEEE10isinstanceb6handle)?

Comment: @DanMašek Sorry I wasn't clear. I mean in c++, not in python. There is no 'isinstance' in c++.

Comment: Did you actually read the pybind11 documentation that link leads to? If so, and it really doesn't satisfy your need, please amend with question with some example code to illustrate the scenario better (including what you tried and didn't work).

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I just assumed it was python. Thanks, that  (`pybind11::isinstance<pybind11::dict>(o)`) worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purpose, pybind11 provides a [C++ counterpart](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#_CPPv4I0_N6detail11enable_if_tINSt10is_base_ofI6object1TE5valueEiEEE10isinstanceb6handle) to Python's [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function.

> `template<typename T, detail::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<object, T>::value, int> = 0>
> bool isinstance(handle obj)`
> Return true if obj is an instance of T. Type T must be a subclass of object or a | class which was exposed to Python as py::class_.

Since [`pybind11::dict`](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#_CPPv44dict) is a subclass of [`pybind11::object`](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#_CPPv46object), this function seems applicable.
In your case, given that `o` is some `pybind11::object`, you could do

```
if (pybind11::isinstance<pybind11::dict>(o)) {
     // o is a dict, do whatever is appropriate...
}
```